# The sum $\sum_{s=2}^{\infty}\zeta(s)^2-1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form, riemann-zeta

It can be easily proven that
$$\sum_{s=2}^{\infty}(\zeta(s)-1)=1$$
I thought of evaluating a very similar looking sum:
$$\sum_{s=2}^{\infty}(\zeta(s)^2-1)$$

- Mathematica cannot solve this, but gives an approximate value of $2.4653$.
- This converges by the comparison test.
  Here is what I did: the formula from [This](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Square_of_Riemann_Zeta_Function) article gives
  $$\sum_{s=2}^{\infty}(\zeta(s)^2-1)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{d(m)}{m-1}-1\right)$$
  where $d(m)$ is the number of divisors of $m$. This equals
  $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac{d(m)}{m-1}-n$$
  But now I am stuck. What can be done now? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no $\gamma$ in any of your expressions.

Comment: @Servaes sorry, corrected that.

Comment: You meant $$\sum_{s=2}^{\infty}(\zeta(s)^2-1)=\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\frac{d(m)m^{-2}}{1-m^{-1}}$$ I doubt there is a closed-form.

Comment: [This question] I asked might be relevant. There is probably not a closed form for it.

Comment: Looks like: $\sum _{s=2}^{\infty } \left(\zeta (s)^2-1\right)=1-\sum _{k=2}^{\infty } \frac{\gamma +\psi \left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)}{k}=1-\sum
   _{k=2}^{\infty } \frac{H_{-\frac{1}{k}}}{k}$ ,but I doubt, there is probably not a closed form for it.